# Daylight Saving Time change schedule trigger for a marginal time

Tags: c#, dst

I'm coding a scheduling app and I'm curious how to handle the following marginal situation concerning the Daylight Saving Time (DST) change:

Say, we're in the time zone where the DST:

- Starts on `2014-Mar-9` at `2:00:00 AM` (clock is adjusted forward)
- Ends on `2014-Nov-2` at `2:00:00 AM` (clock is adjusted backward)

Suppose, an end-user scheduled my app for `2014-Nov-2, 2:00:00 AM`.

Let's assume that the local date/time now is `2014-Nov-2, 1:59:99 AM`.

When should my app fire the schedule -- in 1 second, or in 1 hour and 1 second?

Is there a standard that defines how to deal with this situation?

Comment: How is the user entering the schedule? Can they not be given some prompting about the transition and forced to pick a unique time (which you then just translate to UTC)? If you're just accepting bare date/time inputs, I'd have thought the more interesting scheduling question is when to fire an event scheduled for `2014-Mar-9 02:30:00`?

Comment: Thank you, guys. The end-users pick the time from the date/time picker control and I don't want to make it more difficult for them (dealing with UTC.) As for Tim's concern, I was thinking about a standard of dealing with these marginal dates.

Comment: This is rather opinion based, i.e. off topic on Stack Overflow... But I would say, as you mentioned, this is a marginal case - if you want to keep things simple, fire the trigger in both cases. If you want to make it complex, ask the person in which time does he want the schedule. I'd go for first solution...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yeah, I handle situations like `2014-Mar-9 02:30:00`. In that case the app will show an error that the date does not exist.

Comment: Without some form of extra input from the user, you'll probably end up with a situation where an hour of clock time passes in which it is impossible for the user to schedule events. Is that what you want?

Comment: I've had to write scheduling code for this as well and there's no standard way to handle this other than doing what your users expect. Since we're not your users we can't tell you what the correct thing to do is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) the rules for daylight saving time are:

> ...in spring the clock jumps forward from the last moment of 01:59
>   standard time to 03:00 DST and that day has 23 hours, whereas in
>   autumn the clock jumps backward from the **last moment of 01:59** DST to
>   01:00 standard time, repeating that hour, and that day has 25
>   hours.[37] A digital display of local time does not read 02:00 exactly
>   at the shift to summertime, but instead jumps from **01:59:59.9 forward
>   to 03:00:00.0**.

So while the time and date is different around the world the rules are similar(ignoring Australia's Lord Howe Island which uses a half-hour shift). The hour that jumps backwards or forwards is not touched but the hour that is jumped to.

So in my opinion you should trigger the schedule in one hour and one second.

If you would trigger it in one second and the user wants to stop the schedule at 3 o'clock it would run for two hours instead of one which appears to be incorrect (2-3 = 1 hour).

Comment: That quote seems to be saying that `01:00` in the day with 25 hours occurs twice (after all, the clock reaches `01:59` before it shifts). It's still not clear how a user would set an alert to happen an hour (or less) earlier than your proposed answer.

Comment: +1 for posting the Wikipedia link and esp. for parsing it. (I missed that paragraph.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree about all of the comments that "what you should do" is highly dependent on what your users expect, but I will give my opinion anyway.

If you are scheduling a *single* event, you should be able to test the date and time the user provided to see if it's either invalid (in the spring DST transition), or ambiguous (in the fall DST transition).  In the invalid case, prompt something like "sorry, that time is invalid".  In the ambiguous case, prompt something like "did you mean 1:30 PDT (UTC-7) or 1:30 PST (UTC-8)?" and handle the selection accordingly.

But I'll approach your question from the use case of a *recurring* event, such as a daily alarm clock that fires every day at the same time.  What would I expect as the user of an alarm clock?

- If I schedule a daily time at 2:00 AM, but in the spring transition the clock goes from 1:59:59 to 3:00:00, I'd expect the alarm to go off right at 3:00:00.  I certainly wouldn't want it to go off at 4:00:00 - that would be an *extra* hour.  I also wouldn't want the alarm to not fire at all just because 2:00 didn't *technically* occur.
- If I schedule a daily time at 1:00 AM, but in the fall transition the clock goes from 1:59:59 *back* to 1:00:00 - as a user of this alarm, I would expect it to go off on the *first* occurrence (the daylight time) only.  Occurring twice would just be annoying.

  But here we see how this illustrates needing to know your users expectations.  What if I could tell my alarm clock to let me have that extra hour back?  "Please Mr. Alarm Clock, I'd like to use my extra DST hour to sleep in late.  Wake me up at the *second* occurrence of 1:00." - Now I haven't personally seen any alarm clocks that work this way, but I think you get my point.

Now maybe you're not working with alarm clocks.  Maybe this is a timed wire-transfer or some other time-sensitive item.  You should work through the expected logic and see what makes sense for you.

Be aware that DST rules vary drastically by time zone.  The world does not do DST all at the same time.  Much of it doesn't do it at all.

*For additional clarity on DST behavior, see the charts in the [DST tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).*

Comment: +1 for the wiki link. Man, this DST is a mess. To answer your question, then yes, I need it for a periodic alarm clock type single schedule. So going back to DST -- say, on Windows, how can one get a reliable info on the DST rules for a specific year? I found the `GetTimeZoneInformation` API, but it doesn't seem to take a year.

Comment: In .Net, you can use [the `TimeZoneInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx), with methods like `IsAmbiguousTime`, `IsInvalidTime`, and `GetAdjustmentRules`.  Or, you can consider using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) - a fantastic alternative.